# How to prevent the Android keyboard from hiding screen content?

Tags: android

how to make sure that the keyboard doesn't hide the inputdialog

i tired :

`window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)`

and i added this to the manifest file :

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
```

or in manifest file,

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

By setting `android:windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustPan`, the activity's window will automatically pan to ensure the focused input field is visible when the keyboard is shown.